# Remove words that are less than two characters long AND don't contain a vowel

Tags: awk, sed

You can remove words less than length 2 with
`sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z0-9]\{1\} / /g'`
although I'm not sure how remove only words that don't contain a vowel AND are less than length 2, in one command.

Thus a sentence
`this is my w example of a sentence p`
would end like
 `this is my example of a sentence`

Comment: That sed command doesn't remove all words less than length 2, try `echo 'foo a b bar' | sed ...'`.

Comment: So, you do not have cases like `Word a, Word b, Word ccc`, right? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/EkFqlQ).

Comment: *"Single letter words that aren't a vowel."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!~/[aieou]/ && length($i)<2){ a="" }
    else{ val=(val?val OFS:"")$i            }
  }
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                             ##Starting an awk program from here.
{
  val=""                                          ##Nullifying val value here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                             ##Starting a for loop from here.
    if($i!~/[aieou]/ && length($i)<2){ a="" }     ##Checking condition if field is NOT containing any vowels and length is lesser than 2 then do nothing.
    else{ val=(val?val OFS:"")$i            }     ##Else(in case above condition is FALSE) create val which contains current field value.
  }
  print val                                       ##Printing val here.
}
' Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It seems to remove words that don't contain a vowel, the word "my" gets removed. How do I only print words that contain a vowel OR are of length greater than 2? I tried changing && to || but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @JackNewman, your welcome. For your question `How do I only print words that contain a vowel OR are of length greater than 2? I tried changing && to || but it didn't seem to work.` Try something like: `awk '{val="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/[aieou]/ || length($i)>2){val=(val?val OFS:"")$i}};print val}'  file` once, and let me know then.

Comment: I'm not sure why but a sentence ```this is my w example of a sentence Shh p``` end up being ```this is my w example of a sentence Shh p```

Comment: @JackNewman, It worked fine for me, when I run `echo "this is my w example of a sentence Shh p" | awk '{val="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/[aieou]/ || length($i)>2){val=(val?val OFS:"")$i}};print val}'` it gives me like `this is example of a sentence Shh`.  Could you please check if you have control M characters in your file? Please do like `cat -vet file` once and see if you can see Control M characters in your file?

Answer (score 1):

With a GNU `sed`, you can use

```sh
LC_ALL=C sed 's/[ \t]*\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]\b//g' file
# Or
LC_ALL=C sed 's/[ \t]*\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]\b//gI' file
```

It matches zero or more spaces or tabs, then a consonant word consisting of a single letter where `\b` mark word boundaries. `LC_ALL=C` is used to make sure the bracket expression ranges are compliant with the ASCII table codes.

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/QveBWu).